Algorithm for compound fractions
I have a set of N chemical compounds enumerated 1, 2,..., N. For each compound, I have the fraction of each of its constituents, "A", "B", and so on. Compounds can also contain other compounds, in which case the corresponding fraction is given. For instance, for N = 5, a sample set is
mixes = {
    1: {
        "A": 0.32,
        "B": 0.12,
        "C": 0.15,
        2: 0.41
    },
    2: {
        "C": 0.23,
        "D": 0.12,
        "E": 0.51,
        4: 0.14
    },
    3: {
        "A": 0.24,
        "E": 0.76
    },
    4: {
        "B": 0.13,
        "F": 0.01,
        "H": 0.86
    },
    5: {
        "G": 0.1,
        2: 0.4,
        3: 0.5
    }
}

I would like an algorithm that gives the net fraction of each constituent in every compoound, i.e.
mixes = {
    1: {
        "A": 0.32,
        "B": 0.12 + 0.41 * 0.14 * 0.13,
        "C": 0.15 + 0.41 * 0.23,
        "D": 0.41 * 0.12,
        "E": 0.41 * 0.51,
        "F": 0.41 * 0.14 * 0.01,
        "H": 0.41 * 0.14 * 0.86
    },
    2: {
        "B": 0.14 * 0.13,
        "C": 0.23,
        "D": 0.12,
        "E": 0.51,
        "F": 0.14 * 0.01,
        "H": 0.14 * 0.86
    },
    3: {
        "A": 0.24,
        "E": 0.76
    },
    4: {
        "B": 0.13,
        "F": 0.01,
        "H": 0.86
    },
    5: {
        "A": 0.5 * 0.24,
        "G": 0.1,
        "B": 0.4 * 0.14 * 0.13,
        "C": 0.4 * 0.23,
        "D": 0.4 * 0.12,
        "E": 0.4 * 0.51 + 0.5 * 0.76,
        "F": 0.4 * 0.14 * 0.01,
        "H": 0.4 * 0.14 * 0.86
    }
}

My current approach involves recursion, but I´d like to know if there´s a clever way to do this. Perhaps using a tree-like data structure may help?
EDIT:
for simplicity, assume that there´s no cyclic relationships in the dataset.

Rule #1 of programming: don't be clever. You already have a tree-like data structure (a DAG actually but for the purpose of this task it is works just like a tree a tree) and recursion is the way to deal with it.

Recursion is the way to go. But you can of course still do it in an inefficient way...

With the input data, what are the steps you take to calculate the results by hand? Start by describing those steps clearly in words using whatever human language is most familiar to you.

The case where you don't want (naive) recursion is when there are cyclic relationships.

Here is a recursive solution.  I noted the original mix ratios for each compound add to 1 so there is also a check that the result compounds also add to 1:
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

mixes = {
    1: {
        'A': 0.32,
        'B': 0.12,
        'C': 0.15,
        2: 0.41
    },
    2: {
        'C': 0.23,
        'D': 0.12,
        'E': 0.51,
        4: 0.14
    },
    3: {
        'A': 0.24,
        'E': 0.76
    },
    4: {
        'B': 0.13,
        'F': 0.01,
        'H': 0.86
    },
    5: {
        'G': 0.1,
        2: 0.4,
        3: 0.5
    }
}

def resolve(compound):
    '''Return the components of a compound, recursively adjusted for ratios.
    '''
    for component, ratio in mixes[compound].items():
        # If the component is another compound, recursively report its ratios.
        if isinstance(component, int):
            for subcomponent, subratio in resolve(component):
                yield subcomponent, subratio * ratio
        else:
            yield component, ratio

# A dictionary of dictionaries with default 0.0 float values.
result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))

# Resolve each compound and add up component ratios
for compound in mixes:
    for component, ratio in resolve(compound):
        result[compound][component] += ratio

pprint(result, width=1)

# Checking ratios of result compounds add up to 1
for compound, components in result.items():
    print(compound, sum(component for component in components.values()))

Output:
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00000214CD56FB00>,
            {1: defaultdict(<class 'float'>,
                            {'A': 0.32,
                             'B': 0.127462,
                             'C': 0.2443,
                             'D': 0.049199999999999994,
                             'E': 0.20909999999999998,
                             'F': 0.0005740000000000001,
                             'H': 0.049364}),
             2: defaultdict(<class 'float'>,
                            {'B': 0.0182,
                             'C': 0.23,
                             'D': 0.12,
                             'E': 0.51,
                             'F': 0.0014000000000000002,
                             'H': 0.12040000000000001}),
             3: defaultdict(<class 'float'>,
                            {'A': 0.24,
                             'E': 0.76}),
             4: defaultdict(<class 'float'>,
                            {'B': 0.13,
                             'F': 0.01,
                             'H': 0.86}),
             5: defaultdict(<class 'float'>,
                            {'A': 0.12,
                             'B': 0.007280000000000001,
                             'C': 0.09200000000000001,
                             'D': 0.048,
                             'E': 0.5840000000000001,
                             'F': 0.0005600000000000001,
                             'G': 0.1,
                             'H': 0.04816000000000001})})
1 1.0
2 1.0
3 1.0
4 1.0
5 1.0


Thank you for your answer. My approach was very similar, though the recursive function wasn't a generator. Much appreciated!
